# Image transform is turning my jpegs dark

Tags: image-transforms

I'm experiencing a strange effect where an image transform is causing my images to turn very dark when compared to their originals. I have ImageMagick and gd installed. The images are all sRGB. Some have Adobe RGB profiles, some have no profiles.

The image transform makes the jpeg 1200px wide, height auto, quality high. Not sure what could be causing the problem.

Comment: What image driver are you using, gd or imagick? What colorspace is the original file in? Does it have a color profile?

Comment: @AndréElvan might be onto something. There's this new `preserveColorProfile` config setting that might solve it?

Comment: Yeah, `'preserveImageColorProfiles' => true` could solve it. But ideally, the file should have been saved for web without a profile, or srgb, so.. But there's also this weird thing where old versions of ImageMagick would make images a lot darker when converting from a colorspace without dynamic color range, to a normal jpeg (which has dynamic color space). But, I guess that's a more obscure case.

Comment: @AndréElvan  I have both gd and imagick installed. The file is sRGB. As you suspected 'preserveImageColorProfiles' => true did solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting 'preserveImageColorProfiles' => true, in craft/config/general.php solved the problem.

https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#preserveImageColorProfiles

Note that you need to be running at least [Craft 2.6.2778](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2778) for this config setting to work.

Answer (score 2):

The file probably has a color profile, which gets removed by Craft by default. You can tell Craft to preserve the color profile by setting the `preserveImageColorProfiles` in your config file.

```
'preserveImageColorProfiles' => true
```